# R: how to insert several rows by dplyr (add_row)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have specific row numbers before which I want to paste new rows with some value (e.g., "lol"):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("a","b","c","d"),
                 col2 = c("w","x","y","z"))
n <- c(1, 2, 4)
```

but an argument `.before` of the function `add_row` can only take one value:

```
add_row(df, col1 = "lol", col2 = "lol", .before = n)
  col1 col2
1  lol  lol
2    a    w
3    b    x
4    c    y
5    e    z
```

Is there the fastest way without loops, etc.?

Comment: Your title had `add_column`, changed to `add_row`. And your data.frame was incomplete and not matching the posted data set.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rows.html).

Answer (score 1):

Updated the solution using lapply which is relatively faster than loop

```
  library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("a","b","c","d"),
                 col2 = c("w","x","y","z"))
n <- c(1, 2, 4)
lapply(n,FUN = function(x){df <<-add_row(df, col1 = "lol", col2 = "lol", .before = x)})
df
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I've lost the fourth elements of the column in the example, nevertheless your script doesn't work well anyway. Rows are shuffled.